# Java Proxy Type Error?

Tags: java, eclipse, proxy

I am using Eclipse for Java. When trying to connect to a HTTP proxy, I receive this error for this code:

`Proxy httpProxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, addr);`

Type cannot be resolved or is not a field

Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Proxy class you imported may not be "java.net.Proxy", check your package declaration.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I imported the incorrect package on accident.